# How to debug JSON Serialization error?

Tags: .net, serialization, exception, json.net, elmah

I have the following exception generated inconsistently but frequently:

```
System.Exception: Serialization error - One or more errors occurred., Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0., System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.b__1(String raw)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.b__17(Task`1 t)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41(Task`1 t)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   **at Project.Services.NotificationService.SignalObjectToUser(Object data, String username, Boolean isTypingNotification)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.**
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.b__1(String raw)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.b__17(Task`1 t)
```

The important bit:

```
**at Project.Services.NotificationService.SignalObjectToUser(Object data, String username, Boolean isTypingNotification)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.**
```

My code there:

```
private void SignalObjectToUser(object data, string username, bool isTypingNotification = false) {
        try {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnection(_baseUrl);
            _hubConnection.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            _hubConnection.CookieContainer.Add(_cookie);
            _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("appHub");
            _hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            string serialized = null;
            try {
                List<string> errors = new List<string>();
                serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                    Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args) {
                        errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Delegated serialization error - " + args.ErrorContext.Error.Message));
                    }
                });
                _hubProxy.Invoke((isTypingNotification ? "SendTypingNotification" : "SendClientNotification"), serialized, username).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Serialization error - " + exception.Message + ", " + exception.InnerException.Message + ", " + exception.ToString()));
                throw new Exception("Messaging Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Serialization error - " + e.Message + ", " + e.InnerException.Message + ", " + e.ToString()));
            throw new Exception("Messaging Error");
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out what *exactly* is causing this issue though.  I don't know what key/value pair is generating the exception.  How can I gather more instructive details here?

Comment: The error says the unexpected character is `<` at line 0, position 0.  Are you passing XML to the JSON deserializer?  If so, that's the problem.  Valid JSON will *never* begin with `<`

Comment: @BrianRogers it seems like I am somehow, but I don't know how or when.   I wish there was a way to pre-serialize so that I could see the serialization issue, ha!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you endpoint (_baseUrl) is expected to return JSON, but in fact returns XML or HTML. This can happen if there's an internal server error, bad request, not found or similar, when requesting _baseUrl. If you try to request the URL in a browser, Postman or similar, you will probably see a HTML response together with a status code.

Comment: This was it for me.

Comment: The same error when doing POST from Visual Studio to a remote endpoint. Sending a similar request from Postman helped. Endpoint returned HTML because of misconfigured nginx. nginx and app's logs on the endpoint helped too.